# nginx location regex match everything but home

Tags: nginx, regex

I am trying to restrict access to everything but home "/".

I mean: allow people to access example.com but restrict access with password to any other path: example.com/*any-other-path*.

I have tried multiple combinations of regex with the location directive, but haven't make it work:

```
location ~ /\.+ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location ~ /.+ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location ~ /. {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

And some other but either I restrict access to all (example.com and example.com/*) or don't restrict access to anything.

Could someone point me in the right direction, already read [this](http://www.nginxtips.com/nginx-location-directive/) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and searched in this forum but I am having trouble with this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match files without directories in their path and allow access, and subsequently match everything else and require authentication. For example

```
location ~ ^/[^/]*$ {<no auth directives>}
location ~ ^/.+/.*$ {<some auth directives>}
```